# Required Rails form field does not alert "Please fill out this field"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I am new to Rails forms and have the following form fields:

```
    <%= f.label :name, class: "black-text" %>:
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "white task-card", :required => true %>
    <%= f.label :foo, class: "black-text" %>:
    <% options = [['Option A', 1], ['Option B', 2], ['Option C', 3], ['Option D', 4]] %>
    <%= f.select :foo, options_for_select(options), {}, {:include_blank => true, :required => true, class: "white task-card"} %>
```

If left blank, the text input field will not advance and correctly alerts the user "Please fill out this field," but the select option does not. If the select field is left to its default blank value, the page won't advance, so it works that way, but there is no alert for the user on why nothing is happening. How can I make the browser's standard HTML5 "Please do not fill out this field" alert work for the select field?

Thank you!

Comment: Never found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another hash for providing html options, since the first hash, which, for example, contains `include_blank` option, is for tag options:

```
<% options = [['Option A', 1], ['Option B', 2], ['Option C', 3], ['Option D', 4]] %>
<%= f.select :foo, options_for_select(options), 
    {:include_blank => true, class: "white task-card"}, { :required => true } %>
```

By the way, I don't think `include_blank` option, since the field is required

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a syntax issue:

```
<%= f.select :foo, options_for_select(options), {:include_blank => 
        true, class: "white task-card"}, { :required => true } %>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That gives me the error: "wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1..4)"

Comment: No dice, but thank you! I changed the form now so instead of defaulting to blank it defaults to the existing value (it is an edit form) .. so problem not solved, but workaround reached. Hopefully I can find a solution for my other forms which will not have a preselected value